# Is it possible to emulate/simulate tensor core architecture?

Tags: graphics, nvidia, tensor

Question speaks for itself. It is required for testing purposes. Currently owe GeForce MX330 and would like to simulate different nvidia gpu architecture.. Is that even possible with some tool or to trick the software that requires tensore cores?

I am aware of the cloud services..